# VSCode shows different error than Vue CLI build

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, webpack, vuejs3, vue-cli

I have a completely fresh Vue 3 CLI project in which VSCode shows me an error which is not shown by the CLI/Webpack build even though I've told VSCode to use the TS version from the project (same as CLI/Webpack) instead of the version "shipped" with VSCode:

[image]

Whilst I do know how to fix this issue by removing an "empty" `props` property from `HelloWorld` component (`props: {},`), I'm really curious in understanding why this happens and how to prevent this from causing further confusion in the future.

## Environment

Since I do not know if this is caused by VSCode, Vue CLI, Webpack or some plugin, I'll simply list all possible factors of my environment here:

- VSCode:

  - Version `1.60.2`
  - Plugin [volar](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=johnsoncodehk.volar) installed
  - Used action `Volar: Select Typescript Version` -> `Use workspace version 4.1.6` which results in the following setting within `.vscode/settings.json`: `"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib"`
- Vue:

  - Created project with globally installed CLI version `4.5.13`
  - Settings:

    - Manually
    - TS & Linter/Formatter
    - 3.x
    - No class style components & no babel
    - Linter: ESLint + prettier
  - Only change I've made in the project after creation:

    - Remove property `msg` from component `HelloWorld.vue` + all usages and leave "empty" `props: {},`
- Other env:

  - The project is created within the file system of an WSL2 Ubuntu and opened remotely in VSCode
  - However, the same thing happens when saving the sources in Windows file system and directly opening it from there (no WSL involvement)
- NPM version `6.14.15`
- Node version `14.17.6`

## Reproduction setup

I've uploaded the [whole project here](https://nc.halumi.at/index.php/s/WeNQWEZAY2t32K2).
Reproduction steps (at least on my machine):

- Unzip project
- `npm i` inside the project folder
- Open folder in VSCode
- (Maybe needed) Tell VSCode to use the correct TS version by calling from the "all commands" menu `Select TypeScript Version` -> `Use workspace version 4.1.6`
- VSCode should show the error now when opening `App.vue`

  - If not: Close & reopen VSCode

Answer (score 2):

Using the same TypeScript version is not enough. In Vue 3 and the Volar language server (or VSCode extension) there are two versions of the TypeScript compiler:

- `tsc` - the standard compiler that doesn't understand `.vue` files
- `vue-tsc` - the Volar version of the compiler that understands `.vue` files (but also supports regular tsc files like .ts .json etc.). The Volar VS Code extension is using it, so it understands .vue files too

Your problem is that your webpack configuration is using `tsc` (contary to the Volar extension), so TypeScript doesn't even scan the .vue file for errors.

Can you try doing the following?
In your project dir:

1. Run `npm i vue-tsc`
2. Change your `build` script in package.json to: `vue-cli-service build && vue-tsc --noEmit`

The example from step 2 is kinda wasteful since it'll first run `tsc` as part of `vue-cli-service build` (and show the "DONE Build complete" and then when you wait a bit `vue-tsc` will step start and will start the TS compilation all over again, but report the error)

Comment: I've abandoned Vue in the meantime, so I'm not able to try your suggestions anymore. Sorry for your lost time here, I still really appreciate your effort, maybe it helps someone else! Thanks!